# How to implement spelling insensitive search in django & PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, django, trigram

What I wanted to achieve is, if user enters search for "laptp" then database should return results with actual word "Laptop". Similarly if user enters "ambroidery", then database should return results with both "embroidery" and "embroidred" words containing strings. Hope it clears!!

So what I tried is, I went through whole django documentation and closest thing I found is "Trigram Similarity" search. I followed documentation and tried this:

```
data = 'silk'

data= Product.objects.annotate(
similarity=TrigramSimilarity('description', data)).filter(similarity__gt=0.3).order_by('-similarity')
```

In my database, I have `Products` whose description contains word "silky" but every time I runs this query I get empty query set. Even when I put data value "silky", again I got empty query set.

So first of all suggest me that whether this is right approach for what I wanted to achieve and secondly if it is, then why it is returning empty query set?

Comment: Have you enabled the pg_trgm extension in postgres?

Comment: What do you get if you remove the filter? Do you get the rows you expect first?

Comment: @IainShelvington when I remove the filter, yes first two rows are required but rest are also those which don't contain that specfied word. What's the actual logic of filter?

Comment: Can you see the value of `similarity` for each row? Is it a sensible value?

Comment: @IainShelvington similarity values are as follow: 0.14 , 0.13, 0.09, 0.05 ,0.02 ....0.0  . So what filter should I apply to get only required rows?

Comment: You could just lower the threshold?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212540/discussion-between-dandy-mandy-and-iain-shelvington).